# How to Modify Grails 5 Configuration by Adding Groovy Files

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-5

I have a large number of Grails 2.5 applications that I want to upgrade to  Grails 5, but have been unable to get the configuration to work.  In particular, I want my plugin to set up the data source and Spring Security configuration as it did in Grails 2.5.

In my Grails 2.5 applications, I was able to add files to the configuration by adding this code to the top of `Config.groovy`.

```
if (!grails.config.location || !(grails.config.location instanceof List)) {
    grails.config.location = []
}
    
grails.config.location << ["classpath:jcc-server-config.properties"]
grails.config.location << ["classpath:SecurityConfig.groovy"]
```

But this doesn't work in Grails 5.  I've tried adding an `application.groovy` file, but everything defined in the `application.yml` seems to be set in stone.  Has anybody found a way to add a Groovy file to the Grails configuration that will override or add to the settings in `application.yml`?  YAML will not do because I have logic embedded in the configuration to make it work correctly in different environments.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you remember to include the external-config dependency?  i.e. implementation 'dk.glasius:external-config:3.0.0'

Comment: Thanks.   That gets me a long way toward my goal.  Do you know how to access the existing configuration values from within the Groovy files that I include this way?

Comment: I found that you use grails.util.Metadata.current.getApplicationName() to get the application name, and the other properties will fill in as before.  @DavidBrown - Would you please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to include the external-config dependency? i.e.

```
implementation 'dk.glasius:external-config:3.0.0'
```

Re' your question on accessing config values this way, there should be no difference,  in my apps I get to the config either via grailsApplication.config, or if grailsApplication isn't immediately available(e.g. classes under src), then with Holders, i.e. Holders.grailsApplication.config.